# FullCalendar events (as a function) not populating

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I'm trying to integrate an existing solution into the excellent https://fullcalendar.io calendar but I'm having problems getting events to appear. I don't have much web dev experience, so I expect the answer is quite simple,; here is where I am so far.

On the 'Agenda.aspx' page, I call the function as described in the documentation

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '2017-12-18',
      navLinks: true, 
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, 

      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'Agenda.aspx/GetEvents',
          dataType: 'json',
          data: "{'eventStart': " + start.unix() + ", 'eventEnd': " + end.unix() + "}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          success: function(doc) {
            var events = [];
            $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
              events.push({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                start: $(this).attr('start'),
                end: $(this).attr('end')
              });
            });
            callback(events);
          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
```

The 'GetEvents' is a C# method which queries an SQL database to get events for that month and returns a json string:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string GetEvents(double eventStart, double eventEnd)
    {
        dbHandler m_dbHandler = new dbHandler();

        string JSONString;

        DateTime dt_eventStart = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(eventStart);
        DateTime dt_eventEnd = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(eventEnd);

        DataTable dtEvents = new DataTable();
        if (!m_dbHandler.GetCalendarEventsByDateRange(ref dtEvents))
        {
            throw new Exception("Error retrieving client tokens");
        }
        else
        {
            JSONString = string.Empty;
            JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtEvents);                               
        }

        return JSONString;
    }
```

The method gets called, but the events don't get populated. If I substitute the method call for the below json (which is what the c# method returns), the events are populated:

```
[{ "title": "Booking1", "start": "2017-12-18T09:00:00", "end": "2017-12-18T10:00:00" }, { "title": "Booking2", "start": "2017-12-18T09:00:00", "end": "2017-12-18T11:00:00" }, { "title": "Booking3", "start": "2017-12-18T10:00:00", "end": "2017-12-18T11:00:00" }, { "title": "Booking4", "start": "2017-12-18T12:00:00", "end": "2017-12-18T13:00:00" }, { "title": "Booking5", "start": "2017-12-18T10:00:00", "end": "2017-12-18T12:00:00" }]
```

Here's the page from the guide that I've taken my function from: 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/

Any help appreciated.

ajax debug: 
[ajax debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAprd.jpg)

Comment: have you debugged your ajax call? What happens? Set breakpoints in your JS and C# code, and watch your console and network tab in the browser tools. Check whether it runs, and what it returns - does it send back the expected data, or does it fail somewhere along the line? If so, what goes wrong? What errors or unexpected behaviour do you see? Pinpoint the place where the fault occurs.

Comment: `$(doc).find('event').each(function() {
              events.push({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),
                start: $(this).attr('start'),
                end: $(this).attr('end')
              });
            });` looks suspicious though, having said the above. Isn't `doc` a JSON array? Why are you treating it like a list of jQuery elements? A simple `for` loop will do. Possibly even, you can just pass it directly to the callback function, since you basically seem to be creating new objects with exactly the same attributes as the one you're transforming. Redundant?

Comment: Thanks for helping; can you give me an example of the for loop you had in mind please?

Comment: Just a standard JS for loop over the array...you can google the syntax in 100 places. But here goes: `for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {  events.push({
                title: doc[i].title,
                start: doc[i].start,
                end: doc[i].end
              }); }` and once you see it like that, then, assuming that is actually the structure of what is returned by `doc`, then you can see it's entirely redundant and you could just do `callback(doc)` immediately. But you'd need to confirm the structure of what you get back, if anything - see my earlier debugging comment

Comment: Hi, thanks again, I've debugged the ajax call and I think the issue might be that I'm not getting the data returned by the c# method. I've pasted the debug trace in the original question, can you confirm if this is the issue and what I might be able to do to fix it?

Comment: you got a 200 OK response which indicates success. What's in the "content" property? Alternatively, do `console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));` in your code (it should be the first line of the "success" function) and see what you get. Or look in your network tab and find the line for the ajax call and look inside the "response" tab of that call. You can also set a breakpoint server-side and see what the string looks like just before it returns. Lots of ways to check!

Comment: Ah! If I catch the response in Crome's dev tools, it looks a bit different to the json string that c# is sending. A bit difficult to see in the code below, but it's prefixed with "d". 

{"d":"[{\"title\":\"Booking1\",\"start\":\"2017-12-18T09:00:00\",\"end\":\"2017-12-18T10:00:00\"},{\"title\":\"Booking2\",\"start\":\"2017-12-18T09:00:00\",\"end\":\"2017-12-18T11:00:00\"},{\"title\":\"Booking3\",\"start\":\"2017-12-18T10:00:00\",\"end\":\"2017-12-18T11:00:00\"},{\"title\":\"Booking4\",\"start\":\"2017-12-18T12:00:00\",\"end\":\"2017-12-18T13:00:00\"}]"}

Comment: Ah yes. That's what asp.net webforms does, I remember now. So it's just wrapped the array up as a sub-property within the main returned object. Therefore you just need to send fullCalendar the array by referencing that property. `callback(doc.d);` should do the trick.